# Como faço para atualizar meu Android JSON parsing usando Volley

Tags: android, json

Estou com um problema, sou novo no desenvolvimento para android, estou com uma dúvida.
Meu app esta buscando de um arquivo .json no meu computador, só que quando eu mudo uma palavra e abro meu emulador com o app ele não atualiza. (atualiza quando eu limpo o cache do app). Mas como eu faço pra que ele não precise fazer isso toda vez?

Estou usando este código como exemplo:

```
package info.androidhive.listviewfeed;

import info.androidhive.listviewfeed.adapter.FeedListAdapter;
import info.androidhive.listviewfeed.app.AppController;
import info.androidhive.listviewfeed.data.FeedItem;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Cache.Entry;
import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://192.168.0.23/teste.json";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // These two lines not needed,
        // just to get the look of facebook (changing background color & hiding the icon)
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#B80000")));
        getActionBar().setIcon(
                   new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

        // We first check for cached request
        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
        if (entry != null) {
            // fetch the data from cache
            try {
                String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                try {
                    parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                            if (response != null) {
                                parseJsonFeed(response);
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
     * */
    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("image");
                item.setImge(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

                // url might be null sometimes
                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                feedItems.add(item);
            }

            // notify data changes to list adapater
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Um pouco de código pra mostrar o que está acontecendo ajuda MUITO.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e adicione o código que fica mais fácil de visualizar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não há problema no seu código, amigo. Somente na sua lógica. Você está guardando tudo em cache é lógico que ele sempre vai "puxar" o que está lá, mas se você colocasse uma espécie de atualização de cache na abertura da Atividade principal, seria o correto.

O problema é que você atualiza o Json, mas não tem um controle dessa atualização pelo lado do cliente, ou seja, não há uma espécie de notificação no próprio app, avisando ao cliente para ele atualizar o feed.

Deixe somente este código abaixo e retire toda a condicional do if ao else no onCreate do **MainActivity**:

```
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                            if (response != null) {
                                parseJsonFeed(response);
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
```

Comment: Problema solucionado, muito obrigado.

Comment: Boa noite, este app não fica com as mensagens em utf-8, onde eu posso colocar essa string?